# Create a filename from user input

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script in which i need to create a filename from two user inputs joined together. I have tried a similar code to the one below but its not working.Any help is appreciated.

```
echo -e "\e[1;36m"
read -p " What floor: " floor
echo
echo -e "\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[1;36m"
read -p " what number: " number
echo
echo -e "\e[0m"

filename = $floor + $number + .txt

data > filename
```

Comment: Off-topic: you may want to sanitize the input variables first, to prevent the user from accessing your entire file system.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename="${floor}${number}.txt"
```